# Simple jQuery form validation and sending valid DATA to other jsp

Tags: jquery, validation, jsp

1. I want to Validate this thing and Send this value to other JSP page ..
2. I am new to this concept. I need you to help by " CORRECTING this Form " and suggest me after correction. How can i able to send value to other page.
3. here :- only one field should Enter. In-case of two fields or  `2_fields.NULL()` show a warning. [I did with a `<span id="error"> some thing wrong<span/>`]

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(event) {
       <!-- Real-time Validation -->

                var is_name=$('#contact_name').val();

                 var is_number=$('#contact_number').val();

                 $("#contact_submit button").click(function() {
                       if(($('#contact_number').val().length !=0) && ($('#contact_name').val().length !=0)) {

                               $("#nosearch").hide();
                               $("#search").hide();
                               $("#wrong").show(); 
                       }

                       else if (($('#contact_number').val().length ==0) && ($('#contact_number').val().length ==0) ) {

                               $("#nosearch").show();
                               $("#search").hide();
                               $("#wrong").hide();
                       }
                    else {
                           $("#nosearch").hide();
                           $("#search").show();
                           $("#wrong").hide();

                          // I know some action type of thing should happen here .. 
                          // I don't know what it would be .. help me ...      
                    }
             });
       $("#nosearch").show();
       $("#search").hide();
       $("#wrong").hide();
   });
   ```

   ```
   <form id="contact" method="post" action=" **i don't know how to send a value to other page** ">
       <div>
           <label for="contact_name">Number:</label>
           <input type="text" id="contact_number" size="15" name="number"></input>
       </div>

       <div>
           <label for="contact_email">Name:</label>
           <input type="text" id="contact_name" size="25" name="name"></input> 
       </div>                                      

       <div id="contact_submit">               
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </div>
        <h4 id="wrong"> Only use one column ...<h4>
       <h4 id="nosearch"> Enter any  Information <h4>
       <h4 id="search"> Result about :- .... <h4>
   </form>
   ```

[My fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hari007/0t8wukrg/) :-

Comment: first select jquery library in your fiddle

Comment: i just given that fiddle only for html out put ... i think my code here is very clear with indent too ..

Comment: you are using jquery in your code and It wont work until you select jquery libraries like in your fiddle I have selected jquery 1.7 from first dropdown on sidebar and your code hides the div that you want to hide on document.ready for me

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/0t8wukrg/3/

Comment: yes .. dude .. i selected jquery library ..  and  i need to show only RELEVENT  text about form ... like a 2 field validation ..

if both fields had value  then  >> use only one field <<
if both fields empty . then >> Enter nay one information . <<
else >> " send " that entered value to other JSP page .. 

which is waiting for prinintng Oracle DB values in a table of that JSP page "by query of  either NAME  or  NUMBER "   my entire task for now ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, Is the thing, you are using,

```
<div id="contact_submit">               
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

`submit` button is used for submitting a form. But , In your validation mechanism you have used ,

```
$("#contact_submit button").click(function() {
```

Which would have worked if you have used

```
<input type="button">Submit</button>
```

So, basically `submit` event neutralize your click event. So, either change your button likewise or use different `event` for validation.

If you use click event, then you should manually trigger submit on correct validation case,

```
$("#contact_submit button").click(function() {
   if(valid){
     $("#form-id").submit();
    }
```

But, you can also use Form `submit` event;which is triggered just after you click submit button. In there you can either proceed form submit or reject form submit by checking the correct case.

```
$("#form-id").submit(function(){
   if(invalid){
     //Suppress form submit
      return false;
   }else{
      return true;
   }
});
```

#### Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t8wukrg/5/) for second scenario.

Comment: Name field is not working ... could you help me again where it went wrong ..  Number field is good okay ..  but when i use name field ... it's not ..

Comment: So, What sort of validation do you have for Name?

Comment: You have used contact_number in both case for else if change it to : `else if (($('#contact_name').val().length ==0) && ($('#contact_number').val().length ==0) ) {`

Comment: oopss ... my  blind .. how funny to ask a simple thing ..  and   thanks a lot .. dude .

Answer (score 1):

Ok for what I understood that is you want to send form parameter from one jsp page to other

First change your form action to other page name say `other.jsp`

```
  <form id="contact" method="post" action="other.jsp">
```

Then create a jsp page name other.jsp and to get the value of parameter do

```
<%
String para= request.getParameter("parameterName");  //name or number which is specified in form
%>
```

To print it do

```
<%=para%>
```